# How do I check if .Post has send successfully in Facebook C# sdk?

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I try send the message using the followingcode:

```
//... 
FacebookClient fbClient = new FacebookClient(appId, appSecret);
fbClient.AccessToken = "...";
string to = "user id";
dynamic result = fbClient.Post(String.Format("{0}/feed", to), parameters);
```

but how I can know if the menssage has send to user successfully? what's the returns on case success/erros? I not found some details in the documentation of facebook-sdk-api for C#.

.NET version: `v4.0.30319`

Facebook Assembly version: `5.2.1.0`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by taking reference https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish/ 
 you will have post_id for `result` parameter for successfull call, if fail it should be some json including error message, for example:

```
{
  "error_code": 200,
  "error_msg": "The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action",
  "request_args": [
    {
      "key": "method",
      "value": "stream.publish"
    },
    {
      "key": "access_token",
      "value": "AAAC9okD6ZA7ABABhvJOZBQvUE2OsuHLKEkqlvKKkPDNB9kHfF55DqgKF2raHmSaUSgkpvLtgWniM5CFnu5mxaGODLqvwVz9zBNd1Jd6AZDZD"
    },
    {
      "key": "format",
      "value": "json"
    }
  ]
}
```